How to split data in a .csv file containing double quotes around the fields
In the following statement, what is the split character? 1 double quote or 2?
There are 4 double quotes.
Dim parts As String() = rec.Split(New [Char]() {""""})

It does not make sense, since the data comes like this in a .csv file:
"field1","field2",...

Parsing a CSV file is not easy, as text enclosed in double quotes may contain escaped double quotes, new line characters and separators. Use a library like CsvHelper. See also: Quickstart: Install and use a NuGet package in Visual Studio (Windows only).

If your needs are fairly basic then you can use the TextFieldParser class, which supports reading quoted field values.

The answer to the question is a single double-quote. But as others have commented, that is not the problem.

In VB you need to put four double-quotes to create a String containing one double-quote character. The two on the outside enclose the string. Since double-quote is used to mark the start and end of the String we need to "escape" the double-quote to indicate that we want the String to contain a double-quote.
It's more obvious what's happening if we put characters around the quote:
Dim q = "She said ""Hello, world!"". I was puzzled by this."
Console.WriteLine(q)

Output is
She said "Hello, world!". I was puzzled by this.

P.S. your code has a syntax error, you need to add a c to create a Char as follows:
Dim parts As String() = rec.Split(New Char() {""""c}) 


Thanks for your reply. Will Dim parts As String() = rec.Split(New Char() {""""c})  work  if the data contains certain fields surrounded by double quotes and contain a comma in it, while other fields are not? ie: field1,"field2,abc", field3, field4

I meant to say will Dim parts As String() = rec.Split(New Char() {","c})

The short answer is that you cannot parse a CSV file using a single .Split method call. As @Olivier Jacot-Descombes says above, you should use a library like CsvHelper.
